# Anylogic transporters fleet change speed

Tags: anylogic

i try to change the speed of the transporter in a fleet according to condition. The transporter is moving on a network route.
How can i change the speed?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set the maximum speed of any AGV transporter using `unit.setMaximumSpeed(speed, units)` or set the speed using `unit.setSpeed(speedInMPS)`

Below is an example of setting max speed it inside the AGV fleet object.

[image]

If you need to set the speed limit based on the specific piece of the network the AGV is traveling on it can be done using On Enter/Exit Path or On Enter/Exit Node fields, like the example below.

[image]

But this can get fairly complex if you do this for a number of sections or nodes in your network, then it will be advised to rather use the limit speed option found on paths.

[image]

Comment: @Anat Remember to accept my answer if you found it helpful, and upvote if you think it deserving ;-)